# Counting only visible cells that have been condtionally formatted

Tags: excel, vba

So I am starting to think this just can't be done, here is to hoping that someone here will be able to help me out.

The jist of it is that I have an excel 2013 application that I am working on, it gets data from a sharepoint list, which I filter. The deal is that I apply conditional formatting to a couple of columns in this list, simply to fill in the background color to green or red, based on the text in the cell. Next, I need to get the average of the visible cells, not all the cells that have been formatted, just the ones that are showing up via the filter that I have applied.

Anyway, my code:

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim row As Range

Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
'Set rng = Range("A5:A150")
'For i = 1 To rng.Areas.count

For i = 1 To rng.Areas.Count
    ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(1).Resize(rng.Areas(i).Rows.Count, rng.Areas(i).Columns.Count) _
    = rng.Areas(i).Value

    f = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, i).Value
    If f = "" Then
        f = "<DIV style='font-weight:bold; font-size:24px; font-size:24px; color:orange;'>•</DIV>"
    End If

    c = ("<DIV style='font-weight:bold; font-size:24px; font-size:24px; color:green;'>•</DIV>")
    s = f

    If s = c Then
        Count = Count + 1
    Else
        count2 = count2 + 1
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Let's talk in these comment and not ping Sgdva every time.  Give me an example of one of the formulas you use to color the cells.

Comment: I need to see what formula you use for one of the conditional formatting if I am to help in any way, there is not silver bullet.  I need to use that formula to help modify another formula to get what you want.

Comment: Sure thing. The spreadsheet comes from a sharepoint list, so the formatting is from the dashboard it creates. I have two basic conditions, they both look almost the same:<DIV style='font-weight:bold; font-size:24px; font-size:24px; color:green;'>•</DIV> and <DIV style='font-weight:bold; font-size:24px; font-size:24px; color:red;'>•</DIV>

Comment: No, why does one get set to red and the other to green?  Not the code itself but why.  Under what conditions does it set the color?

Comment: @Scott Craner, the color is determined by a number of things, being what the other fields are set to at the time. So if next review date = today, then it will be set to red, otherwise, green.

Comment: okay so we do `SUMIFS(columnToSum,NextReviewDateColumn,INT(TODAY()))` for sum.

Comment: For Count: `COUNTIF(NextReviewDateColumn,INT(TODAY()))` and for average `AVERAGEIFS(columnToAverage,NextReviewDateColumn,INT(TODAY()))`

Comment: Ok, so I might be doing something wrong here, but I added the formula that you told me to for the countif: =COUNTIF(L5:L300,INT(TODAY())) and it is giving me 10, though there are only 9 green cells.

Comment: Then the criteria is wrong somehow.  See if you can find the tenth one that has today's date and see why it is not green.

Comment: I only have 9 visible rows, and all the dates are today or greater than today, Not sure what is going on, but thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

Color given by conditional formatting can't be read through VBA. 
However, if you filter the data prior to it, why don't you try:

```
SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

Comment: If you read the code, OP has `Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`

Comment: My bad, didn't read the first line, just read those: If f = "" Then
        f = "<DIV style='font-weight:bold; font-size:24px; font-size:24px; **color:orange**;'>•</DIV>" The color here is never going to be solved, however and yet again, if the filter already filtered by oranges for example, why to check color again?

Comment: Color given by conditional formatting **can** be read through VBA using the [Range.DisplayFormat property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838814.aspx).

Comment: So I am using this SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) in my code, as you can see above.

Comment: Hi Sgdva, the reason I am looking at the colors of the cells is to get an average of the green vs red or orange.

Comment: @Mike You can do this with formulas based on the condition that sets the color instead of the color itself.

Comment: @Jeeped As an OT: Holly where you were when I asked that years ago? I couldn't find it anywhere and had to do a workaround for those scenarios. However, I tried to set an argument to the function and returns value, though, as warned in the site, it doesn't work for UDF. Mike, either Jeeped or Scott approach should work, IMHO: I'd go with the Display format to avoid a second check for the thing that colored the cells in the first place.

Comment: @Scott Craner, Hi Scott, this sounds interesting, how would I do this? I don't really need a step by step, just something to get me started.

Comment: @Mike did you see my comment above from 28 minutes ago?

Comment: @Scott Crane So it would appear that this doesn't work. I did the Formulas --> more functions, statistical averageif(A6:A300,A6,E3) and it gives me back the same results regardless of which filter is being used.

Comment: @mike let's move this conversation to the comments under you question.